# What would be a best practice to program mathematical calculations?

Tags: math, coding-style, finance

I'm programming some financial software needing to program not very complicated mathematical formulas.

After writing the code, it is not readable anymore - i.e - you can't easily discern what was the original formula.

What would be a good way to program mathematical formulas so they could be easily read later on?

For example, programming a calculation for a loan with a fixed interest rate:

`(TotalValue*monthlyInterest*Math.pow((1+monthlyInterest),totalPayments))/(Math.pow((1+monthlyInterest),totalPayments) - 1)`

Though using meaningful variables, the formula is not readable. But if you will look at this formula written in a classical mathematical notation on a page - you will easily know what's going on (really basic math).

How would you even take this formula and write it in a readable way.

**Clarification**

I'm not talking about any specific language. This should be the same for any high-level language.
The example uses Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add local variables that are abbreviations of the long name. As they are local, their definition will be right above the formula. This could look like

```
TV = TotalValue;
mi = monthlyInterest;
N = totalPayments;

MR = ( TV*mi*Math.pow( 1+mi, N ) ) / ( Math.pow( 1+mi, N ) - 1)

MonthlyRate = MR;
```

where you then see that you can simplify the formula to

```
MR = (TV*mi) / ( 1 - Math.pow( 1+mi , -N) - 1)
```

Comment: Definitely looks better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, it is not possible to convert Excel formulas to equations
But for clarity, you could recreate the Equation in the Equation Editor and put it next to the cell. This way it is immediately obvious what you are doing.

Another way would be to create the Mathematical Equation and add a macro. This way you could calculate your values in VBA.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear - but I'm not talking about excel... just any programming language

Comment: oh okay, sorry i got a bit confused. you could break up the equation and lower the amount of variables per line.

Comment: But wouldn't you then lose clarity of the whole equation as a whole? You won't be able to understand the equation with one glance - as you would with a real equation.

Comment: in that case i would recommend putting the equation in a function. This way you get something along the lines of "calculateValue(x, y, z).
Making it pretty obvious what the equation requiers and returns.